Would an 18" pedestal lavatory with 4" separation from wall and toilet meet code?
First of all, I am located in Fairfax, VA. I am aiming to turn a 1/2 bathroom into a full bath. The bathroom dimensions are 7'4" x 6'4". I would like to add a pedestal lavatory, toilet and a shower with a 36" wide glass partition. So the overall dimensions I were envisioning would be as follows: 4" space + 18" diameter lavatory + 6" space + 30" for the toilet + 2'6" for the shower.
I found this link: https://www.fairfaxcounty.gov/landdevelopment/sites/landdevelopment/files/assets/documents/pdf/publications/basement-details.pdf
Page 9 has the code for Fairfax county, I imagine MC has something similar
Showers. Showers and shower compartments must meet the following requirements.
•Shower compartments must have a minimum total area of 900 square inches and a minimum dimension of 30 inches in any direction.
•Shower compartments may have a minimum dimension of 25 inches provided it maintains a cross sectional area of 1,300 square inches.
•Hinged shower doors must open outward.
•All glass which encloses as shower must be safety glazed.
•Shower control valves must be scald resistant (in accordance with ASSE/ANSI 1016) with a hot water limit of 120 degree F.
Fixture clearances. Toilets, sinks and showers shall have the minimum clearances listed below.
•21 inches in front of sinks and toilets.
•24 inches in front of shower stall opening.
•4 inches between two adjacent sinks.
•4 inches between a sink and a toilet.
•4 inches between a sink and a wall.
•2 inches between a sink and a bathtub.
•15 inches clearance from a toilet's centerline to an adjacent fixture or wall on each side.
Although, my bathroom is NOT in a basement, this leads me to think that my concept would be compliant. However I am non sure since I don't have 60" for lavatory and toilet all together (30" + 30"). Thank you all in advance!

you are going to apply for permit, and they will tell you

And since you're probably gonna need to give the permit office a sketch of your proposed layout, you might as well do the same for us...
